# Ambigious use of 'Subscript' Compiler Error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to run my xcode project onto my iPhone but everytime i try to run it, i get

> Ambigious use of 'Subscript'

However if i run the project on a xcode simulator it works fine? Any ideas? 
Heres the code

```
            for ev in jsonObject! {

                let catName = ev["CATEGORY_NAME"]
                let venName = ev["EVENT_VENUES"]
                let shortName = ev["SHORT_NAME"]
                let eventName = ev["EVENT_NAME"]
                let dsc = ev["EVENT_DESCRIPTION"]
                let img = ev["EVENT_IMAGE"]

                if let category = catName, theShortName = shortName, theEventName = eventName, theDesc = dsc, theImg = img, theVenues = venName{

                    if theVenues.count < 1 {
                        continue
                    }


                    if let fv = theVenues[0]{
                        if let vn = fv["VENUE_NAME"] as? String {
                            let event = Event(data: ["CATEGORY_NAME" : category, "SHORT_NAME" : theShortName,"EVENT_NAME" : theEventName,"EVENT_DESCRIPTION" : theDesc,"EVENT_IMAGE" : theImg,"VENUE_NAME" : vn])
                            self.events.append(event!)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

I'm getting the error on this line

```
if let fv = theVenues[0]{
```

Here is where the data is initialised

```
class Event {
var shortName : String?
var name : String?
var desc : String?
var category : String?
var location : String?
var image : String?


// pass data object directly into initializer.
init?(data: [String:AnyObject]) {
    guard let eventShortName = data["SHORT_NAME"] as? String else { return }
    guard let eventName = data["EVENT_NAME"] as? String else { return }
    guard let eventDesc = data["EVENT_DESCRIPTION"] as? String else { return }
    guard let categoryName = data["CATEGORY_NAME"] as? String else { return }
    guard let eventLocation = data["VENUE_NAME"] as? String else { return }
    guard let eventImage = data["EVENT_IMAGE"] as? String else { return }
    shortName = eventShortName
    name = eventName
    desc = eventDesc
    category = categoryName
    location = eventLocation
    image = eventImage

}
```

}

Comment: can you show the declaration part of theVenus array ? The problem might be the type declaration at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, i have added my class initializer if that's any help?

Comment: I'm just wondering what type is theVenus array. You might need to declare it's type before using it like "theVenues[0]".